# How to solve the quadratic equation problem with a strict proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider $f(x)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$ with $n\le a\le b\le n+1$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Find the range of $\min\{f(n),f(n+1)\}$

Sorry I just made a mistake,now is fixed. This problem is obvious in geometry. But how to proof it with algebra?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab=(x-a)(x-b)$ [if so this is a hint]